# Como filtrar um item do banco de dados, através de um campo do tipo List?

Tags: c#, linq

Tenho o a entidade `MessageEntity` que contém várias sessões (`SectionsEntity`) que por sua vez, contém vários atendimentos (`TreatmentEntity`).

Preciso trazer as mensagens, filtradas pelo seu `Id`, filtradas pelas sessões ativas e pelos atendimentos ativos.

Segue as entidades:

```
public class MessageEntity: AggEntity
{
....
     public MessageEntity()
     {

     }

     public virtual ICollection<SectionsEntity> Sections { get; private set; }
...
}

public class SectionsEntity : AggEntity
{
    ...
    public SectionsEntity() { }
    ..
    public virtual ICollection<TreatmentEntity> Treatments { get; private set; } = new List<TreatmentEntity>();
    public DateTime? FinishAt { get; private set; } 
}

public class TreatmentEntity : AggEntity
{
...
    public AttendanceEntity()
    {

    }
    public DateTime? FinishAt { get; private set; }
....    
}
```

Tenho uma classe de extensão que retorna a MessageEntity:

```
public static IQueryable<MessageEntity> ActiveSectionsByMessageId(this IQueryable<MessageEntity> source, Guid id)
{
    return source.Where(x => x.Id == id)
        

}
```

Como trazer somente o `Message` que tenha os campos `FinishAt == null` ?

Muito obrigado

Comment: Essa sua consulta está um tanto estranha... você fala em message e apresenta o método de consulta em `Chat` uma entidade que você nem apresentou

Comment: @LeandroAngelo editei, obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa, fiz um projetinho console e mudei algumas coisas nas suas classes como o encapsulamento para poder demonstrar como ficaria uma consulta no LINQ para fazer a filtragem segue o código:

```
public class MessageEntity
    {

        public MessageEntity()
        {
            Sections = new List<SectionsEntity> {
                new SectionsEntity {Id = 1, FinishAt = null},
                new SectionsEntity {Id = 2,FinishAt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)},
                new SectionsEntity {Id = 3,FinishAt = null},
                new SectionsEntity {Id = 4,FinishAt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2)},
                new SectionsEntity {Id = 5,FinishAt = null},
                new SectionsEntity {Id = 6,FinishAt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)},
                new SectionsEntity {Id = 7,FinishAt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10)},
            };
        }

        public virtual ICollection<SectionsEntity> Sections { get; private set; }

    }

    public class SectionsEntity
    {

        public SectionsEntity() { 
            Treatments = new List<TreatmentEntity> {
                new TreatmentEntity {Id = 1, FinishAt = null},
                new TreatmentEntity {Id = 2,FinishAt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)},
                new TreatmentEntity {Id = 3,FinishAt = null},
                new TreatmentEntity {Id = 4,FinishAt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2)},
                new TreatmentEntity {Id = 5,FinishAt = null},
                new TreatmentEntity {Id = 6,FinishAt = null},
                new TreatmentEntity {Id = 7,FinishAt = null},
            };
        }

        public virtual ICollection<TreatmentEntity> Treatments { get; private set; } = new List<TreatmentEntity>();
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime? FinishAt { get; set; }
    }

    public class TreatmentEntity
    {

        public TreatmentEntity()
        {

        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime? FinishAt { get; set; }

    }
```

E a minha classe program ficou assim:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var message = new MessageEntity();

            var somenteNull = message.Sections.Where(w => w.FinishAt == null && w.Treatments.Any(w => w.FinishAt == null)).ToList();

            foreach (var item in somenteNull)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Id: {item.Id} -> Finalizado: {item.FinishAt}");
            }
        }

    }
```

A saída foram as 3 instancias que possuem null tanto na SectionsEntity quanto na TreatmentEntity segue:

```
$ dotnet run
Id: 1 -> Finalizado: 
Id: 3 -> Finalizado: 
Id: 5 -> Finalizado:
```